# Xcode Documentation Subscribe Buttons

Tags: xcode

When I go to **Help > Documentation** in Xcode, I notice the various "Subscribe" buttons in the left sidebar.

What exactly happens when I click a subscribe button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I click "subscribe" it simply starts downloading new updated documentation. And after that I suppose it will check time by time for a new available one to download.

Answer (score 2):

[Subscribing to Documentation Feeds](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeWorkspace/200-Documentation_Access/chapter_6_section_9.html)

"When a new doc set becomes available, it’s listed under the feed name with a Get button next to it. Click the button to download and install the doc set.

When a new release of a doc set you have on your computer is available, an Update button appears next to the doc set’s name. Click the button to download and install the new version of the doc set."